# React not triggering events bound to JSX Elements created in array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to work on a small react + typescript (1.6) application that edits slideshows.

So the app is simple. On the left i have a sidebar that renders all the existing slides and on click, it loads a canvas on the right where the user can edit the content.

Also, the user can mark the slide as "hidden" or remove it.

The code looks like this:

```
renderSlide(item: SlideBaseModel.Slide, index: number): JSX.Element {
    let cx = React.addons.classSet;
    let _classes = cx({
        "fa": true,
        "fa-eye": !item.visible,
        "fa-eye-slash": item.visible
    });

    return (
        <li className="slide-item"  draggable={true} onClick={this.onSlideClick.bind(this)} key={item.id}>
            <div className="index">{index + 1}</div>
            <div className="control remove" onClick={this.onRemoveSlideClick.bind(this)}>
                <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="control toggle-visibility" onClick={this.onToggleSlideVisibility.bind(this)}>
                <i className={_classes}></i>
                </div>
            <SlideComponent
                type={item.type}
                title={item.title}
                visible={item.visible}
                content={item.content}
                path={item.path}/>
        </li>);
}

render() {
    let _slides = this.state.slides.map(this.renderSlide, this);
    let cx = React.addons.classSet;
    let classes = cx({
        "sidebar": true,
        "sidebar-visible": this.props.visible
    });

    return (<ul className={classes}>
            {_slides}
            <li className="slide-item slide-add" onClick={this.onAddSlideClick.bind(this) }></li>
        </ul>);
}
```

Now, whenever I click on any of the methods bound onClick in the "renderSlide" method, the event isn't triggered.

I have tried with things like:

```
onClick={(e) => {console.log(e)}}
```

and the issue still occurs.

Instead of map i tried to create an array and fill it inside a forEach, but it's not working.
If i call `this.renderSlide(this.state.slides[0])` inside the render method, the events work so it must be something related to the array.

**Additional pieces of code**

*Slide props*

```
interface SlideProps {
    type: Enums.SlideType;
    title: string;
    content?: string;
    path?: string;
    visible: boolean;
}
```

*Generated JS code*

```
Sidebar.prototype.renderSlide = function (item, index) {
    var itemData;
    var cx = React.addons.classSet;
    var _classes = cx({
        "fa": true,
        "fa-eye": !item.visible,
        "fa-eye-slash": item.visible
    });
    return (React.createElement("li", {"className": "slide-item", "draggable": true, "onClick": this.onSlideClick.bind(this), "key": item.id}, React.createElement("div", {"className": "index"}, index + 1), React.createElement("div", {"className": "control remove", "onClick": this.onRemoveSlideClick.bind(this)}, React.createElement("i", {"className": "fa fa-times"})), React.createElement("div", {"className": "control toggle-visibility", "onClick": this.onToggleSlideVisibility.bind(this)}, React.createElement("i", {"className": _classes})), React.createElement(SlideComponent, {"type": itemData.type, "title": itemData.title, "visible": itemData.visible, "content": itemData.content, "path": itemData.path})));
};
Sidebar.prototype.render = function () {
    var _slides = this.state.slides.map(this.renderSlide, this);
    var cx = React.addons.classSet;
    var classes = cx({
        "sidebar": true,
        "sidebar-visible": this.props.visible
    });
    return (React.createElement("ul", {"className": classes}, _slides, React.createElement("li", {"className": "slide-item slide-add", "onClick": this.onAddSlideClick.bind(this)})));
};
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

---

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to see if the EventPluginHub.putListener is called (and with what argument) for these elements, but it's not. I tried what Basarat suggested and the issue still occurs.

I fail to see the problem here. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was caused by the fact that i retrieved the data in the `componentDidMount` method instead of the initialization (yeah, i'm a newbie).

Right now i'm having another issue, related to this, but i will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

> the events work so it must be something related to the array

perhaps the `key` is not unique. Consider : `<li className="slide-item"  draggable={true} onClick={this.onSlideClick.bind(this)} key={index}>`

## General code review

Note that `bind` is considered harmful as you lose any type safety. Here is its signature from `lib.d.ts`

```
bind(thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
```

As you can see it returns `any`. Removing it might help find some other *typing* bug you have in your code.

> `renderSlide(item: SlideBaseModel.Slide, index: number): JSX.Element {` and `this.state.slides.map(this.renderSlide, this);`

Recommend you use `renderSlide = (item: SlideBaseModel.Slide, index: number): JSX.Element => {` and `this.state.slides.map(this.renderSlide);`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I start to believe it's because TS1.6 and TSX Compilation :(